# How is Darth Vader's ship able to catch the Tantive IV over Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, a-new-hope

Depending on which source you use, such as this one compiled from the video games and appearing in *Behind the Magic*:
[image]
*(source: [theforce.net](http://www.theforce.net/swtc/units.html))*

a Corellian Corvette class ship (aka Rebel Blockade Runner class or CR90 corvette), including Princess Leia's Tantive IV, is as fast or faster than an Imperator (or Imperial I) class star destroyer (Vader's ship at the beginning of *A New Hope*).  The Tantive IV should have been able to easily escape by keeping out of range until they were able to jump to hyperspace.

We also see no use of TIE fighters, bombers or interceptors, and that no interdictor ship appears. Given all that, how did Vader's ship get close enough to open fire and disable the princess' ship?

Comment: We do however see only the final moments of the chase, we therefore do not know how heavily damaged the Tantive IV already was... the flight from Toprawa might have depleted her fuel supply or she overheated her engines or any other technical problem....

Comment: I could be conflating the flight of the *Tantive IV* with the capture of the *Millennium Falcon*, but I think in the radio play there's mention of a tractor beam.

Comment: @PhilPursglove - The radio play just says that her ship was "intercepted on her approach and forced to land under escort"; http://youtu.be/bEPba_tdFbk?t=30m49s

Comment: @bmwurm - That entire storyline is now considered non-canon

Comment: In actual fact none of this material is canon any more, so the question doesn't even need asking.

Comment: @DarthSatan - Not true. The novelisations are canon, unless they conflict with the films themselves; http://starwarsalways.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/novelisations-are-part-of-the-canon/

Comment: A question would probably be how long it would have taken for the ship to calculate a new hypserspace route (IF the engine was ok at least in the film itself I dont remember anything aside form the shield generators getting blown out). For running by jumping we only see small ships like light freightrers (the falcon) and that one is faster than star destroyers anyway. It could be that a bigger ship just would take too long to calculate the coordinates while under fire or the first shots were a surprise and denied them of any chance to jump (as stated we only see the last part of the chase)

Comment: One interesting side fact: Just watched episode IV again.....imperial star destroyers almost catched up to the millenium falcon "they almost have us" just before they made the jump to lightspeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new Rogue One novelisation indicates that the Tantive IV was in terrible shape even before the Imperials got to it in the Tatooine system. It suffered some sort of explosive impact (presumably a blast from the Devastator)  before it managed to escape from Scarif.

> ***The Tantive IV wasn’t ready to fly, let alone fight. It had been the
> subject of frantic repairs during the lightspeed voyage from Yavin to
> Scarif,** secure in the hangar of the Profundity where it had lain,
> stubbornly malingering, since its last mission. Even after its host
> vessel had arrived in-system and joined the battle against the
> Imperial armada, Captain Raymus Antilles and his engineers and droids
> had worked desperately to make the corvette spaceworthy—to seal the
> leak in its hyperdrive motivator and clean the buildup in its exhaust
> ports. Admiral Raddus had made the situation clear: Every ship in the
> fleet had a part to play.*
>
> ...
>
> ***The Tantive IV wasn’t ready to fly, but it flew.** It emerged from the burning wreck of the cruiser and sped away from Scarif. **For a blessed few seconds it moved swiftly, confidently through space. Then the ship rocked again and echoed with thunder and sparks.** From his station on the bridge, Raymus could smell circuits melting.*
>
> *“Star Destroyer closing!” called the officer at the tactical console. Raymus didn’t recognize the face—one of Raddus’s men.*
>
> *He erased the fear from his own expression. “Get us into hyperspace,” he said. “Make sure you secure the air lock. And prepare the escape pods.”*
>
> ***The Tantive IV might jump out of the system, but it was hurt and it would be pursued.** Best not to take chances.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>

---

According to the <s>Alan Dean Foster</s> [George Lucas novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_%28novel%29) of A New Hope, the ship had its "principal solar sail" destroyed in the first few seconds of tangling with the Devastator in Tatooine orbit (which explains why they didn't attempt to land). Artoo tells C-3P0 that shutting down the main reactor and hyperdrive was necessary, presumably to prevent the ship from exploding, which explains why the ship didn't attempt to outrun the Star Destroyer or enter hyperspace.

> *“Did you hear that?” he [C3P0] inquired rhetorically of his patient
> companion, referring to the throbbing sound. “They’ve shut down the
> main reactor and the drive.”*
>
> ...
>
> *Artoo did not comment immediately. Barrel torso tilted backward,
> powerful legs gripping the deck, the meter-high robot was engrossed in
> studying the roof overhead. Though he did not have a head to cock in a
> listening posture like his friend, Artoo still somehow managed to
> convey that impression. A series of short beeps and chirps issued from
> his speaker. To even a sensitive human ear they would have been just
> so much static, but to Threepio they formed words as clear and pure as
> direct current. “Yes, I suppose they did have to shut the drive down,”
> Threepio admitted, “but what are we going to do now? We can’t enter
> atmosphere with our main stabilizer fin destroyed. I can’t believe
> we’re simply going to surrender.”*

---

As a matter of interest, the (now thoroughly non-canon) [Star Wars Radio play](http://youtu.be/bEPba_tdFbk?t=30m49s) mentions that her ship was...

> *"...intercepted on approach and forced to land under escort".*

Which obviously departs from the accepted film canon. The landing was in the original draft script but not in the final screenplay.

Comment: The Executor was at Tatooine?

Comment: @T.J.L. - Lol. When you spot obvious errors, don't hesitate to edit them

Comment: I figured I'd bring it to your attention. If the ship had a proper name, you'd be likely to know it.

Answer (score 1):

**It was faster but it didn't matter**

From the opening shot of Episode IV we can clearly see the Tantive IV outrunning the Star Destroyer before it gets damaged, which probably means that the Star Destroyer popped out of hyperspace close to them and proceeded to shoot.

In fact, in Rogue One:

> We see the very same Star Destroyer jump from hyperspace into the final space battle, blocking ships that are attempting to escape, some of which do crash into its shields.

As for why the Tantive IV did not jump into hyperspace immediately, I'd guess that, since their mission was to locate Obi Wan Kenobi on Tatooine, they were either distracted trying to locate him from orbit, or unwilling to run and have the Empire wonder why they were there and summon reinforcements.

Alternatively, they might've known that the Star Destroyer would've tracked them anywhere they jumped to, and it stands to reason that a massive warship such as an SD would have enough fuel stores to outlast the Tantive IV at a game of cat and mouse.

Answer (score -1):

At the time of the attack, neither Princess Leia nor the Tantive IV were wanted by the Empire.  Just the opposite, it was the personal ship of an Imperial Senator (the Princess).

> "This is a consular ship… we're on a diplomatic mission" -- Captain Antillies

Fleeing an Imperial Star Destroyer would blow their cover.  Flying at maximum speed would also blow their cover (I'm assuming doing so puts strain on the engines and is not fuel efficient, so it's not a normal procedure).  If the Imperials approached, they would have no choice but to "fly casual" and try to bluff their way through to keep their cover.  They certainly wouldn't expect the Imperials to open fire on a Senator's ship.  Only as a last resort would they try to flee.

To put an analogy in real life, if you were driving along with contraband in your trunk, you wouldn't speed away if you saw a police car headed your way.

Comment: They *were* wanted by the Empire, their cover story (that they were on a peaceful diplomatic mission) was their last throw of the dice to try to convince the Imperial troops not to search the ship.

Comment: @Richard Did they know they were wanted?  And did they believe the Imperials would fire upon and board a consular ship?

Comment: they were certainly *hoping* they wouldn't. To continue the analogy, if you were carrying the entire Allied war plans in 1944 would you rely on the Nazis respecting your fake Swiss passport?

Comment: @Richard It wasn't fake, she was an actual Senator and it was an actual consular ship. Diplomats smuggle all sorts of things in wartime. [Wookipedia claims there was an Imperial cover up of the affair](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tantive_IV#History) implying their attack was not entirely legal.  "Afterward, the corvette was destroyed and the entire crew was killed. Imperial propaganda, including a falsified report by the survey vessel Wide-Eyed, would later proclaim that an asteroid storm caused the destruction of the Tantive IV."

Comment: This is based on non-canon EU novels. In the film (and novelisation) all we know is that they claim to be a diplomatic mission. In reality, their possession of stolen military secrets probably negates this normal protection.

Comment: One thing though even in the film vader said that "no survivors" part. Thus it can be seen that he didnt want the political storm to happen for him attacking a consular ship. Problem is though @Schwern they were already under attack so it would have been logical for them to flee as the empire doesnt usually start hitting consular ships just for the fun (civilian ships maybe but the senate still had SOME might at that time (until later in the film at least when it was dissolved)).

Comment: There's no question they were wanted by the Empire.  What I'm saying is they didn't know they were wanted and so would have tried to bluff past a Star Destroyer on their protection as a consular ship.  This is a plausible explanation why they'd allow themselves to get in range despite being able to match speeds with a Star Destroyer.  Once the shooting started, of course they flee.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other.  I've [created a chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19775/how-is-darth-vaders-ship-able-to-catch-the-tantive-iv-over-tattoine) and would like to hear how you think the chase played out in more detail.